# How do I rename a dataframe index and make it count from 1 without fragmenting the header?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want a dataframe where the index starts from `1`. I also want to rename the index.

It doesn't matter what order these operations are performed, I just want to ensure that the header isn't fragmented.

This is surely a duplicate question, but I can't seem to find it(!)

This doesn't work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
df.index += 1
df.rename_axis('rank')

>>>
        A   B
rank        
   1    1   4
   2    2   5
   3    3   6
```

Nor does this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
df.rename_axis('rank')
df.index += 1

>>>
    A   B
1   1   4
2   2   5
3   3   6
```

Desired result:

```
rank    A   B   
   1    1   4
   2    2   5
   3    3   6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) is not in place, but returns a new DataFrame. You would need to assign the output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
df.index += 1
df = df.rename_axis('rank')

print(df)
```

If you want a single command, use [`Index.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.rename.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})

df.index = df.index.rename('rank')+1

print(df)
```

Modified `df`:

```
      A  B
rank      
1     1  4
2     2  5
3     3  6
```

If you want to display it on the same level, use [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html):

```
print(df.reset_index().to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
 rank  A  B
    1  1  4
    2  2  5
    3  3  6
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, the index name is not a header and therefore will not be on the same line by default.

Option 1) Best for printing

**Print you dataframe in another way, e.g. use df.to_markdown or best [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)**

```
from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(df, headers=["rank"]+list(df.columns)))
```

---

Option 2)

You could make your own "index" column and "hide" the index, but in general that is not a good idea as the dataframe loses functionality!
Only use this for printing.

```
df["rank"] = df.index + 1
df.index = [""]*len(df)
```

---

Option 3)

you could slightly cheat by naming your first column rank but put only empty strings inside. In that case remember that you did it.

```
df["rank"] = ""
df.columns = ["rank"] + [c for c in df.columns if c != "rank"] # you can do this in other ways too
df.index += 1
```

---

There might be a printoption for pandas, but I haven't seen it yet.

---